# Fetch multiple child-notes from same node with xmlstarlet in a block

Tags: xml, linux, xpath, xmlstarlet

I have an XML file containing multiple user entries with some user data like name, email and other data. It seems that this could be done using multiple `--value-of` (`-v`) arguments like this:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t --nl -v "//n:title" -v "//n:email" ~/tests/test-xml.xml

Some user
Some user #2
Some user #3some.user@example.com
some.user2@example.com
some.user3@example.com
```

But they're not together, it looks like the tool process all `<title>` elements first and then all `<email>` ones. I like to have the following format:

```
Some user
some.user@example.com
Some user #2
some.user2@example.com
...
```

Found out that I need the xpath function `concat` for this. Now I get them at least with comma seperated:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t -m "//n:entry" -v "concat(current()//n:title, ',', current()//n:email)" ~/tests/test-xml.xml
Some user,some.user@example.comSome user #2,some.user2@example.comSome user #3,some.user3@example.com
```

That's exactly what I need, but when I set `\n` as delimiter instead of `,`, it will just print `\n` instead of doing a line break. The same happens for `\\n` and `\r\n`. As a workaround, this could be replaced using sed like this: `sed 's/,/\n/g'`

However, this doesn't solve the problem that there is no new line between `some.user@example.comSome user #2`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t -m "//n:entry" -v "concat(current()//n:title, ',', current()//n:email)" ~/tests/test-xml.xml | sed 's/,/\n/g'
Some user
some.user@example.comSome user #2
some.user2@example.comSome user #3
some.user3@example.com
```

How can I realize this? Would prefer a solution without additional `sed` command if it makes sense and would be possible.

#### Workaround

The only workaround I found is to nest it in another `concat` call to add another char, that identifies the placed where another new line is needed and could be replaced with `\n` too like this:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t -m "//n:entry" -v "concat(concat(current()//n:title, ',', current()//n:email), '|', '')" ~/tests/test-xml.xml | sed -E 's/[,|]+/\n/g'
Some user
some.user@example.com
Some user #2
some.user2@example.com
Some user #3
some.user3@example.com
```

Altough this works, it seems like a nasty workaround to me. Would like to know if there is a more clean way to do this. I guess it's possible with a deeper experience of `xmlstarlet` and maybe also `xpath`.

#### Test XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app"
  xmlns:snx="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn"
  xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <opensearch:totalResults
    xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">67
  </opensearch:totalResults>
  <opensearch:startIndex
    xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">1
  </opensearch:startIndex>
  <opensearch:itemsPerPage
    xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">100
  </opensearch:itemsPerPage>

  <entry>
    <title>Some user</title>
    <contributor>
      <email>some.user@example.com</email>
    </contributor>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <title>Some user #2</title>
    <contributor>
      <email>some.user2@example.com</email>
    </contributor>
  </entry>

  <entry>
    <title>Some user #3</title>
    <contributor>
      <email>some.user3@example.com</email>
    </contributor>
  </entry>

</feed>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `-m "//n:entry" -v "n:title" --nl -v "n:contributor/n:email" --nl`? You'd have an extra newline at the end, but hopefully that's not an issue.

Comment: It can be done with xpath 2.0, but for that you'll need something like xidel.

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to output a newline (`--nl`) after every `entry`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t -m "//n:entry" -v "n:title" --nl -v "n:contributor/n:email" --nl input.xml
```

but this will output an extra newline at the end of the output:

```
Some user
some.user@example.com
Some user #2
some.user2@example.com
Some user #3
some.user3@example.com
```

An alternative is to output a newline before an `entry` if it's not the first. (Using -i (xsl:if) and -b (break nesting))...

```
xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" -t -m "//n:entry" -i "position() > 1" --nl -b -v "n:title" --nl -v "n:contributor/n:email" input.xml
```

output:

```
Some user
some.user@example.com
Some user #2
some.user2@example.com
Some user #3
some.user3@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xmllint here but the use of xpath and xargs/printf should still be the same:

```
xmllint --format --xpath "concat('\"',/feed/entry/title,'\" \"',/feed/entry/contributor/email,'\"')" ~/tests/test-xml.xml | xargs printf "%s\n"
```

With xpath, we format the data by adding quotations and a space between the title and the email. We then pipe through to xargs and printf to print each entry on a separate line.